# Who am I? is my question

Tags: riddle

I have a lot of siblings, but I have the longest name of them all.  In fact all of my brothers and sisters have single syllable names, but mine is the only one with multiple syllables.

My prior sibling loves peace, my next sibling likes finding things, and I like to ask questions.

So, here is my question, who am I?

Comment: This question has become the site's Hot Network Question. Think you could give it a better title?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I believe you are:

> The letter W

Your prior sibling loves peace:

> The 'V' sign using your fingers is a symbol for peace. Thanks to M Oehm for pointing this out!

Your next sibling likes finding things:

> X-ray. X marks the spot.

You like asking questions:

> Who, where, what, when, why?

You're the longest name of them all:

> W is the only letter with a multi-syllable pronunciation.

Comment: +1 Nice one! Not sure about the V though... vegan? XD

Comment: Because the V sign is also used as peace gesture, depending on whether it's being made by Chruchill or by some hippies?

Comment: Wow, 2 minutes to answer correctly.  Great job!

Comment: The single syllable thing rung a bell. I'd once seen a puzzle where you were asked to explain the set of numbers '1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 3 1 1 1', and as soon as I thought back to that puzzle, this one basically solved itself. Nice quick puzzle :)